# How to redirect to another path in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Hello I want to redirect to an internal path.

Example

```
https://mylink.com/some-page.html and my fetch link
https://mylink.com/another-page.html
```

I use `router.replace` but it adds the last link inside of the first one. How to fix this to replace the first link by the second?

I use

```js
window.location
```

Is it possible to do it with another solution thanks to vue router?

The idea is

```js
params {'another-page'}
```

but the API returns the whole URL: https://mylink.com/another-page.html, not just the path.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I have to admit that I did not understand anything in this question. Don't use `window.location` that's for sure. If you want to move to an internal path but you only have the URL, cut the URL to get only the part that is interesting here. If you want to move to an external URL, use `router.push('https://google.com')`. Still, one of your question was based on internal and this one is asking for an external URL? Not sure to properly scope this one.

Comment: @kissu the 2 questions is the same problem I explained myself poorly sorry but this response is the good response i'm split my url and add pathname finally my question is an internal url don't external thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take the received URL and cut the last part of it to have only the path. Then you could use the Vue router to move to the according page inside of your Nuxt app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.$router.push('/another-page');` for internal links.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using named routes, you could do something like `this.$router.push(AnotherPage);`